# How to hit the run method of a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, runnable-jar

I have runnable jar of a spring boot application. I have used it as a library in my java project. Now I want to hit the run method of this library, but I am getting an exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer". How should I go about this?

Thanks in advance

Hi All,
I have solved the issue on my own. The run/main method of the spring boot library will be called like CLassName.methodName(Parameters) i.e. after importing the class from the library.

Make a library using jfx plugin. Rather then using the eclipse IDE.

The error I was getting was because of the dependencies which were to be added in the build path of the project.

Do these things and one is good to go.

PS: Hope this helps anyone in future.

Comment: Could you please state the exception? Even if it is not specific it will be more accurate than just verbal interpretation. What steps did you undertake. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Through the REST API.

Comment: NoClassDefFound!Its unable to load the configuration class when I call the main method from my code.

Comment: Maybe, instead of using the runnable jar as lib and calling the main method inside it, you could call using Process, like: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar your-runnalbe.jar"); from the rest api or anyway you want.

Comment: Can you show your main class, `pom.xml` and stacktrace with exceptions from console?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 15 more

Comment: SpringBootServletInitializer is extended from the class that is being called... `public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
  SpringBootWebApplication.main(args);
  System.out.println(args);
 }`

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi as the project is a java project it has no pom. I have imported a springboot project to this project as a runnable jar.

Comment: @AnkitPande If you don't have a `pom.xml`, how do you manage your dependencies?

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi I have  a pom.xml but it is for a spring boot project. Please read the question. I have two projects one has a pom and the second doesn't has a pom

Answer (score 0):

For a Spring Boot application, which needs to be used as a library, refer this link:

[Creating a Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)

Comment: I am not making a multi-module project to begin with. I want to use my spring boot application as a library in my java project.

Comment: @AnkitPande Why don't you move the shared stuff out into a pure library?

Comment: Hi @Ankit, please refer to the link again, i think that is what you would want : How to create a multi-module project with Spring Boot, in which there is a library jar and a main application that uses the library. You could also use it just to see how to build a library on its own (i.e. a jar file that is not an application).

Comment: @TechFree I have achieved this with mvn jfx plugin. Thanks.